# What is difference between Uri.withAppendedPath() and Uri.withAppendedId() in Android

Tags: android

What is difference between Uri.withAppendedPath() and Uri.withAppendedId() in Android as I have seen the android developers site that, one comes from the android.content.ContentUris class while other comes from android.net.Uri class
So what is the difference between both of them?

Comment: http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentUris.java#109